# Catching js violation on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

does anyone know if it is possible to catch or listen to violations on chrome?

I'm getting intermittent violation messages when requesting permissions and I would like to define different behaviors depending if there was violation.

I tried try-catch which didn't work.

this is the message I get: "Only request permission in response to a user gesture." - when I get it the permission window doesn't show. - is there a way to detect if the permission window was displayed or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I suggest you take the [tour] and read the [ask] page, you will even get a badge for this! Can you please precise what you mean by "js violation"? You should also add the code you tried to the question. Good luck!

Comment: Violations are just warnings - they are browser specific and do not effect your script execution

Comment: Kaddath - I've updated and elaborated my question. Mortz - yet when I get this violation the permission window is not displayed.

Comment: This is still very unclear, what kind of permission are you talking about? things like geolocation? Which window doesn't display? Please share the relevant part of your code, it's really hard to answer in the abstract.